# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « $2 » Position : 40

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need help please! how to set up the column in @query nativeSql jpa. I test that and it gives an error like this! I believe that the parameter does not work

```java
@Query(value = "select * from usernotvalid order by ?1 ?2 offset ?3 limit ?4",nativeQuery = true)
public List<User> findAllNotValid(String colonne,String ordre,int debut,int fin);
```

Comment: this is the error : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « $2 »
  Position : 40

Comment: and this is the code : @Query(value = "select * from usernotvalid order by ?1 ?2 offset ?3 limit ?4",nativeQuery = true) public List findAllNotValid(String colonne,String ordre,int debut,int fin);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a comma between columns in ORDER BY

```
@Query(value = "select * from usernotvalid order by ?1, ?2 offset ?3 limit ?4",nativeQuery = true)
```